# JSP Help - Parameter not working

Tags: java, jsp

I'm making a small web application using servlets and JSPS. (All the code will be shown in screenshots as the code keeps messing up when I try to put it in normally).

This is a snippet of the servlet class:

http://prntscr.com/irm32y

This is a snippet of the output JSP file:

http://prntscr.com/irm40z

And this is a snippet of the form JSP:

http://prntscr.com/irm4d7

For some reason, I'm not allowed to use the "polygon.digits" EL. I can only put numbers in there. (It's to specify how many decimals the user wants the answer to)

Comment: Paste your code here, so it is easily readable.

Comment: Not able to. It messes up a lot.